# How to add new, large breakpoint in Bootstrap 4 (CSS Only)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

I faced a problem, when extra large Bootsrap 4 max container width, which is 1140px, is not wide enough. Because I want my websites looks good on big monitors too, and bootstrap grid is extremely narrow. The easiest way is to expand maximum width is to overwrite the .container max-width, like:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
     max-width: 1540px;
  }  
}
```

But I want not just to expand the `xl max-width`. I wish to add a new full-fledged breakpoint, with all of BS4 grid possibilities, columns, display modes, spacing etc. Like `col-xxl` or something. As the result it should look like:

```
<div class="col-xxl-2 col-xl-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 text-xxl-center"></div>
```

Any ideas, how to do it correctly using CSS?

Comment: for that you need to use `SASS`

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to compile from SASS i.e. in [this file](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/scss/_variables.scss) search for `$grid-breakpoints:`

Comment: SASS is to dificult for me now, im looking for simple css colution.

Answer (score 4):

Use `SASS` in your project and add file `custom.scss` ( you can choose whatever name you want )

Add

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
        xs: 0,
        sm: 576px,
        md: 768px,
        lg: 992px,
        xl: 1200px,
        xxl: 1600px
);

@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

Now you can use `xxl` in bootstrap `mixins` but if you want to use `col-xxl-*`, you need to compile `custom.scss` with `node-sass` and use that compiled bootstrap file as your current bootstrap file.

DOCS: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/#grid-tiers

**OTHER SOLUTION**

Use the below site to make your breakpoints and after download it.

https://themestr.app/customize

Comment: Do you have simple css solution?

Comment: @Pavel.T, use my other solution

Comment: Thx, I will use this solution in my future projects. Im not proficient with SASS.

Comment: With [themestr.app](https://themestr.app/customize) you can add the new breakpoint and download the CSS.

Comment: Your answer is great. If you are familiar with Sass - this is the only right solution. About themestr.app - pretty nice too, but in case when i'd like to update my bootstrap version - customize BS every time on all sites is too complicated. In some cases it's enough just to add CSS quick fix. But, anyway, your answer is pretty good, I also learned something new for myself. Up

Comment: glad you like my answer @focus.style

Comment: This is not the CSS solution. This options are playing around SASS.

Comment: Please read the comment, I also provide other solution just for css

Answer (score 4):

Fortunately for you, I've made a solution in some of my porjects, which fully matches your request.
Faced the same problem and made a little CSS extencion.

Just create a **bootstrap-grid-xxl.css**, or you can use any css stylsheet, just make sure, that it should be loaded after original **bootstrap 4 css** files (to overwrite container max-width). And adding a code below:

```
/* BS4 Grid XXL breakpoint */

/* adding col-xxl */
.col-xxl, .col-xxl-1, .col-xxl-2, .col-xxl-3, .col-xxl-4, .col-xxl-5, .col-xxl-6, .col-xxl-7, .col-xxl-8, .col-xxl-9, .col-xxl-10, .col-xxl-11, .col-xxl-12, .col-xxl-auto {position: relative; width: 100%; padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 15px;}

@media (min-width: 1570px){
  /* expanding BS4 max-width */
    .container {max-width: 1540px;}

  /* grid columns xxl */
    .col-xxl {-ms-flex-preferred-size: 0; flex-basis: 0; -webkit-box-flex: 1; -ms-flex-positive: 1; flex-grow: 1; max-width: 100%;}
  .col-xxl-auto {-webkit-box-flex: 0; -ms-flex: 0 0 auto; flex: 0 0 auto; width: auto; max-width: none;}  
    .col-xxl-1 {-webkit-box-flex: 0; -ms-flex: 0 0 8.333333%; flex: 0 0 8.333333%; max-width: 8.333333%;}
    .col-xxl-2 {-webkit-box-flex: 0; -ms-flex: 0 0 16.666667%; flex: 0 0 16.666667%; max-width: 16.666667%;}
    .col-xxl-3 {-webkit-box-flex: 0; -ms-flex: 0 0 25%; flex: 0 0 25%; max-width: 25%;}
    .col-xxl-4 {-webkit-box-flex: 0; -ms-flex: 0 0 33.333333%; flex: 0 0 33.333333%; max-width: 33.333333%;}
    .col-xxl-5 {-webkit-box-flex: 0; -ms-flex: 0 0 41.666667%; flex: 0 0 41.666667%; max-width: 41.666667%;}
    .col-xxl-6 {-webkit-box-flex: 0; -ms-flex: 0 0 50%; flex: 0 0 50%; max-width: 50%;}
    .col-xxl-7 {-webkit-box-flex: 0; -ms-flex: 0 0 58.333333%; flex: 0 0 58.333333%; max-width: 58.333333%;}
    .col-xxl-8 {-webkit-box-flex: 0; -ms-flex: 0 0 66.666667%; flex: 0 0 66.666667%; max-width: 66.666667%;}
    .col-xxl-9 {-webkit-box-flex: 0; -ms-flex: 0 0 75%; flex: 0 0 75%; max-width: 75%;}
    .col-xxl-10 {-webkit-box-flex: 0; -ms-flex: 0 0 16.666667%; flex: 0 0 16.666667%; max-width: 16.666667%;}
    .col-xxl-11 {-webkit-box-flex: 0; -ms-flex: 0 0 16.666667%; flex: 0 0 16.666667%; max-width: 16.666667%;}
    .col-xxl-12 {-webkit-box-flex: 0; -ms-flex: 0 0 16.666667%; flex: 0 0 16.666667%; max-width: 16.666667%;}

  /* order xxl */
  .order-xxl-0 {-webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1; -ms-flex-order: 0; order: 0;}
  .order-xxl-1 {-webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2; -ms-flex-order: 1; order: 1;}
  .order-xxl-2 {-webkit-box-ordinal-group: 3; -ms-flex-order: 2; order: 2;}
  .order-xxl-3 {-webkit-box-ordinal-group: 4; -ms-flex-order: 3; order: 3;}
  .order-xxl-4 {-webkit-box-ordinal-group: 5; -ms-flex-order: 4; order: 4;}
  .order-xxl-5 {-webkit-box-ordinal-group: 6; -ms-flex-order: 5; order: 5;}
  .order-xxl-6 {-webkit-box-ordinal-group: 7; -ms-flex-order: 6; order: 6;}
  .order-xxl-7 {-webkit-box-ordinal-group: 8; -ms-flex-order: 7; order: 7;}
  .order-xxl-8 {-webkit-box-ordinal-group: 9; -ms-flex-order: 8; order: 8;}
  .order-xxl-9 {-webkit-box-ordinal-group: 10; -ms-flex-order: 9; order: 9;}
  .order-xxl-10 {-webkit-box-ordinal-group: 11; -ms-flex-order: 10; order: 10;}
  .order-xxl-11 {-webkit-box-ordinal-group: 12; -ms-flex-order: 11; order: 11;}
  .order-xxl-12 {-webkit-box-ordinal-group: 13; -ms-flex-order: 12; order: 12;}

  /* text-align xxl */
    .text-xxl-center {text-align: center!important;}
    .text-xxl-left {text-align: left!important;}
    .text-xxl-right {text-align: right!important;}  

  /* float xxl */
  .float-xxl-left {float: left!important;}
  .float-xxl-right {float: right!important;}
  .float-xxl-none {float: none!important;}

  /* display xxl */
  .d-xxl-none {display: none!important;}
  .d-xxl-inline {display: inline!important;}
  .d-xxl-inline-block {display: inline-block!important;}
  .d-xxl-block {display: block!important;}
  .d-xxl-table {display: table!important;}
  .d-xxl-table-cell {display: table-cell!important;}
  .d-xxl-table-row {display: table-row!important;}
  .d-xxl-flex {display: flex!important;}
  .d-xxl-inline-flex {display: inline-flex!important;}

  /* offsets xxl */
  .offset-xxl-1 {margin-left: 8.333333%;}
  .offset-xxl-2 {margin-left: 16.666667%;}
  .offset-xxl-3 {margin-left: 25%;}
  .offset-xxl-4 {margin-left: 33.333333%;}
  .offset-xxl-5 {margin-left: 41.666667%;}
  .offset-xxl-6 {margin-left: 50%;}
  .offset-xxl-7 {margin-left: 58.333333%;}
  .offset-xxl-8 {margin-left: 66.666667%;}
  .offset-xxl-9 {margin-left: 75%;}
  .offset-xxl-10 {margin-left: 83.333333%;}
  .offset-xxl-11 {margin-left: 91.666667%;}

  /* spacing xxl */
  .m-xxl-0{margin:0!important}.mt-xxl-0,.my-xxl-0{margin-top:0!important}.mr-xxl-0,.mx-xxl-0{margin-right:0!important}.mb-xxl-0,.my-xxl-0{margin-bottom:0!important}.ml-xxl-0,.mx-xxl-0{margin-left:0!important}.m-xxl-1{margin:.25rem!important}.mt-xxl-1,.my-xxl-1{margin-top:.25rem!important}.mr-xxl-1,.mx-xxl-1{margin-right:.25rem!important}.mb-xxl-1,.my-xxl-1{margin-bottom:.25rem!important}.ml-xxl-1,.mx-xxl-1{margin-left:.25rem!important}.m-xxl-2{margin:.5rem!important}.mt-xxl-2,.my-xxl-2{margin-top:.5rem!important}.mr-xxl-2,.mx-xxl-2{margin-right:.5rem!important}.mb-xxl-2,.my-xxl-2{margin-bottom:.5rem!important}.ml-xxl-2,.mx-xxl-2{margin-left:.5rem!important}.m-xxl-3{margin:1rem!important}.mt-xxl-3,.my-xxl-3{margin-top:1rem!important}.mr-xxl-3,.mx-xxl-3{margin-right:1rem!important}.mb-xxl-3,.my-xxl-3{margin-bottom:1rem!important}.ml-xxl-3,.mx-xxl-3{margin-left:1rem!important}.m-xxl-4{margin:1.5rem!important}.mt-xxl-4,.my-xxl-4{margin-top:1.5rem!important}.mr-xxl-4,.mx-xxl-4{margin-right:1.5rem!important}.mb-xxl-4,.my-xxl-4{margin-bottom:1.5rem!important}.ml-xxl-4,.mx-xxl-4{margin-left:1.5rem!important}.m-xxl-5{margin:3rem!important}.mt-xxl-5,.my-xxl-5{margin-top:3rem!important}.mr-xxl-5,.mx-xxl-5{margin-right:3rem!important}.mb-xxl-5,.my-xxl-5{margin-bottom:3rem!important}.ml-xxl-5,.mx-xxl-5{margin-left:3rem!important}
  .p-xxl-0{padding:0!important}.pt-xxl-0,.py-xxl-0{padding-top:0!important}.pr-xxl-0,.px-xxl-0{padding-right:0!important}.pb-xxl-0,.py-xxl-0{padding-bottom:0!important}.pl-xxl-0,.px-xxl-0{padding-left:0!important}.p-xxl-1{padding:.25rem!important}.pt-xxl-1,.py-xxl-1{padding-top:.25rem!important}.pr-xxl-1,.px-xxl-1{padding-right:.25rem!important}.pb-xxl-1,.py-xxl-1{padding-bottom:.25rem!important}.pl-xxl-1,.px-xxl-1{padding-left:.25rem!important}.p-xxl-2{padding:.5rem!important}.pt-xxl-2,.py-xxl-2{padding-top:.5rem!important}.pr-xxl-2,.px-xxl-2{padding-right:.5rem!important}.pb-xxl-2,.py-xxl-2{padding-bottom:.5rem!important}.pl-xxl-2,.px-xxl-2{padding-left:.5rem!important}.p-xxl-3{padding:1rem!important}.pt-xxl-3,.py-xxl-3{padding-top:1rem!important}.pr-xxl-3,.px-xxl-3{padding-right:1rem!important}.pb-xxl-3,.py-xxl-3{padding-bottom:1rem!important}.pl-xxl-3,.px-xxl-3{padding-left:1rem!important}.p-xxl-4{padding:1.5rem!important}.pt-xxl-4,.py-xxl-4{padding-top:1.5rem!important}.pr-xxl-4,.px-xxl-4{padding-right:1.5rem!important}.pb-xxl-4,.py-xxl-4{padding-bottom:1.5rem!important}.pl-xxl-4,.px-xxl-4{padding-left:1.5rem!important}.p-xxl-5{padding:3rem!important}.pt-xxl-5,.py-xxl-5{padding-top:3rem!important}.pr-xxl-5,.px-xxl-5{padding-right:3rem!important}.pb-xxl-5,.py-xxl-5{padding-bottom:3rem!important}.pl-xxl-5,.px-xxl-5{padding-left:3rem!important}
  .m-xxl-auto{margin:auto!important}.mt-xxl-auto,.my-xxl-auto{margin-top:auto!important}.mr-xxl-auto,.mx-xxl-auto{margin-right:auto!important}.mb-xxl-auto,.my-xxl-auto{margin-bottom:auto!important}.ml-xxl-auto,.mx-xxl-auto{margin-left:auto!important}

}
```

It should be although a solution on **Sass**. But i'm not so strong in Sass structure of BS4. I think, if you are familiar with BS4 Sass - you could add XXL breakpoint using the same principe like in my code above.

Comment: you can not use like that, it affects some specificity concept of CSS

Comment: Why can't I do that? It works perfectly in my projects. On OpenCart stores, for example.

Comment: you can't overwrite all properties like that, for me this is not a valid solution but yes its working solution.

Comment: For example, all Opencart default template is made on Bootstrap. And there are a lot of BS fixes in original OC stylesheet. Maybe it is not a pure valid solution, but i think CSS clear solution should take place too.

Comment: .col-xxl-10 .col-xxl-11 .col-xxl-12
has error, near % section + multiple errors around the code.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above answers worked for me so i've created the following [gist](https://gist.github.com/ronaldgrn/ecc3ac46fabbd0b8dc967cf7a82712b7) based off Bootstrap 4.6.0.

By default it changes your .container to the new 1600 size but you can just comment out the first two blocks to disable that.

```
// Adapted from bootstrap 4.6.0

.container-xxl {
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

// 95%
@media (min-width: 1600px) {
  .container, .container-sm, .container-md, .container-lg, .container-xl, .container-xxl {
    max-width: 1520px;
  }
}

.col-xxl-1, .col-xxl-2, .col-xxl-3, .col-xxl-4, .col-xxl-5, .col-xxl-6, .col-xxl-7, .col-xxl-8, .col-xxl-9, .col-xxl-10, .col-xxl-11, .col-xxl-12, .col-xxl,
.col-xxl-auto {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}


@media (min-width: 1600px) {
  .col-xxl {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
    flex-basis: 0;
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .row-cols-xxl-1 > * {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .row-cols-xxl-2 > * {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 50%;
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
  .row-cols-xxl-3 > * {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
    flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
    max-width: 33.333333%;
  }
  .row-cols-xxl-4 > * {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 25%;
    flex: 0 0 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
  }
  .row-cols-xxl-5 > * {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 20%;
    flex: 0 0 20%;
    max-width: 20%;
  }
  .row-cols-xxl-6 > * {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 16.666667%;
    flex: 0 0 16.666667%;
    max-width: 16.666667%;
  }
  .col-xxl-auto {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .col-xxl-1 {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 8.333333%;
    flex: 0 0 8.333333%;
    max-width: 8.333333%;
  }
  .col-xxl-2 {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 16.666667%;
    flex: 0 0 16.666667%;
    max-width: 16.666667%;
  }
  .col-xxl-3 {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 25%;
    flex: 0 0 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
  }
  .col-xxl-4 {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
    flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
    max-width: 33.333333%;
  }
  .col-xxl-5 {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 41.666667%;
    flex: 0 0 41.666667%;
    max-width: 41.666667%;
  }
  .col-xxl-6 {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 50%;
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
  .col-xxl-7 {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 58.333333%;
    flex: 0 0 58.333333%;
    max-width: 58.333333%;
  }
  .col-xxl-8 {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 66.666667%;
    flex: 0 0 66.666667%;
    max-width: 66.666667%;
  }
  .col-xxl-9 {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 75%;
    flex: 0 0 75%;
    max-width: 75%;
  }
  .col-xxl-10 {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 83.333333%;
    flex: 0 0 83.333333%;
    max-width: 83.333333%;
  }
  .col-xxl-11 {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 91.666667%;
    flex: 0 0 91.666667%;
    max-width: 91.666667%;
  }
  .col-xxl-12 {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .order-xxl-first {
    -ms-flex-order: -1;
    order: -1;
  }
  .order-xxl-last {
    -ms-flex-order: 13;
    order: 13;
  }
  .order-xxl-0 {
    -ms-flex-order: 0;
    order: 0;
  }
  .order-xxl-1 {
    -ms-flex-order: 1;
    order: 1;
  }
  .order-xxl-2 {
    -ms-flex-order: 2;
    order: 2;
  }
  .order-xxl-3 {
    -ms-flex-order: 3;
    order: 3;
  }
  .order-xxl-4 {
    -ms-flex-order: 4;
    order: 4;
  }
  .order-xxl-5 {
    -ms-flex-order: 5;
    order: 5;
  }
  .order-xxl-6 {
    -ms-flex-order: 6;
    order: 6;
  }
  .order-xxl-7 {
    -ms-flex-order: 7;
    order: 7;
  }
  .order-xxl-8 {
    -ms-flex-order: 8;
    order: 8;
  }
  .order-xxl-9 {
    -ms-flex-order: 9;
    order: 9;
  }
  .order-xxl-10 {
    -ms-flex-order: 10;
    order: 10;
  }
  .order-xxl-11 {
    -ms-flex-order: 11;
    order: 11;
  }
  .order-xxl-12 {
    -ms-flex-order: 12;
    order: 12;
  }
  .offset-xxl-0 {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .offset-xxl-1 {
    margin-left: 8.333333%;
  }
  .offset-xxl-2 {
    margin-left: 16.666667%;
  }
  .offset-xxl-3 {
    margin-left: 25%;
  }
  .offset-xxl-4 {
    margin-left: 33.333333%;
  }
  .offset-xxl-5 {
    margin-left: 41.666667%;
  }
  .offset-xxl-6 {
    margin-left: 50%;
  }
  .offset-xxl-7 {
    margin-left: 58.333333%;
  }
  .offset-xxl-8 {
    margin-left: 66.666667%;
  }
  .offset-xxl-9 {
    margin-left: 75%;
  }
  .offset-xxl-10 {
    margin-left: 83.333333%;
  }
  .offset-xxl-11 {
    margin-left: 91.666667%;
  }
}



// group 3
@media (min-width: 1600px) {
  .d-xxl-none {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .d-xxl-inline {
    display: inline !important;
  }
  .d-xxl-inline-block {
    display: inline-block !important;
  }
  .d-xxl-block {
    display: block !important;
  }
  .d-xxl-table {
    display: table !important;
  }
  .d-xxl-table-row {
    display: table-row !important;
  }
  .d-xxl-table-cell {
    display: table-cell !important;
  }
  .d-xxl-flex {
    display: -ms-flexbox !important;
    display: flex !important;
  }
  .d-xxl-inline-flex {
    display: -ms-inline-flexbox !important;
    display: inline-flex !important;
  }
}

// group 4
@media (min-width: 1600px) {
  .flex-xxl-row {
    -ms-flex-direction: row !important;
    flex-direction: row !important;
  }
  .flex-xxl-column {
    -ms-flex-direction: column !important;
    flex-direction: column !important;
  }
  .flex-xxl-row-reverse {
    -ms-flex-direction: row-reverse !important;
    flex-direction: row-reverse !important;
  }
  .flex-xxl-column-reverse {
    -ms-flex-direction: column-reverse !important;
    flex-direction: column-reverse !important;
  }
  .flex-xxl-wrap {
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap !important;
    flex-wrap: wrap !important;
  }
  .flex-xxl-nowrap {
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap !important;
    flex-wrap: nowrap !important;
  }
  .flex-xxl-wrap-reverse {
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap-reverse !important;
    flex-wrap: wrap-reverse !important;
  }
  .flex-xxl-fill {
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto !important;
    flex: 1 1 auto !important;
  }
  .flex-xxl-grow-0 {
    -ms-flex-positive: 0 !important;
    flex-grow: 0 !important;
  }
  .flex-xxl-grow-1 {
    -ms-flex-positive: 1 !important;
    flex-grow: 1 !important;
  }
  .flex-xxl-shrink-0 {
    -ms-flex-negative: 0 !important;
    flex-shrink: 0 !important;
  }
  .flex-xxl-shrink-1 {
    -ms-flex-negative: 1 !important;
    flex-shrink: 1 !important;
  }
  .justify-content-xxl-start {
    -ms-flex-pack: start !important;
    justify-content: flex-start !important;
  }
  .justify-content-xxl-end {
    -ms-flex-pack: end !important;
    justify-content: flex-end !important;
  }
  .justify-content-xxl-center {
    -ms-flex-pack: center !important;
    justify-content: center !important;
  }
  .justify-content-xxl-between {
    -ms-flex-pack: justify !important;
    justify-content: space-between !important;
  }
  .justify-content-xxl-around {
    -ms-flex-pack: distribute !important;
    justify-content: space-around !important;
  }
  .align-items-xxl-start {
    -ms-flex-align: start !important;
    align-items: flex-start !important;
  }
  .align-items-xxl-end {
    -ms-flex-align: end !important;
    align-items: flex-end !important;
  }
  .align-items-xxl-center {
    -ms-flex-align: center !important;
    align-items: center !important;
  }
  .align-items-xxl-baseline {
    -ms-flex-align: baseline !important;
    align-items: baseline !important;
  }
  .align-items-xxl-stretch {
    -ms-flex-align: stretch !important;
    align-items: stretch !important;
  }
  .align-content-xxl-start {
    -ms-flex-line-pack: start !important;
    align-content: flex-start !important;
  }
  .align-content-xxl-end {
    -ms-flex-line-pack: end !important;
    align-content: flex-end !important;
  }
  .align-content-xxl-center {
    -ms-flex-line-pack: center !important;
    align-content: center !important;
  }
  .align-content-xxl-between {
    -ms-flex-line-pack: justify !important;
    align-content: space-between !important;
  }
  .align-content-xxl-around {
    -ms-flex-line-pack: distribute !important;
    align-content: space-around !important;
  }
  .align-content-xxl-stretch {
    -ms-flex-line-pack: stretch !important;
    align-content: stretch !important;
  }
  .align-self-xxl-auto {
    -ms-flex-item-align: auto !important;
    align-self: auto !important;
  }
  .align-self-xxl-start {
    -ms-flex-item-align: start !important;
    align-self: flex-start !important;
  }
  .align-self-xxl-end {
    -ms-flex-item-align: end !important;
    align-self: flex-end !important;
  }
  .align-self-xxl-center {
    -ms-flex-item-align: center !important;
    align-self: center !important;
  }
  .align-self-xxl-baseline {
    -ms-flex-item-align: baseline !important;
    align-self: baseline !important;
  }
  .align-self-xxl-stretch {
    -ms-flex-item-align: stretch !important;
    align-self: stretch !important;
  }
}

// group 5
@media (min-width: 1600px) {
  .m-xxl-0 {
    margin: 0 !important;
  }
  .mt-xxl-0,
  .my-xxl-0 {
    margin-top: 0 !important;
  }
  .mr-xxl-0,
  .mx-xxl-0 {
    margin-right: 0 !important;
  }
  .mb-xxl-0,
  .my-xxl-0 {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
  }
  .ml-xxl-0,
  .mx-xxl-0 {
    margin-left: 0 !important;
  }
  .m-xxl-1 {
    margin: 0.25rem !important;
  }
  .mt-xxl-1,
  .my-xxl-1 {
    margin-top: 0.25rem !important;
  }
  .mr-xxl-1,
  .mx-xxl-1 {
    margin-right: 0.25rem !important;
  }
  .mb-xxl-1,
  .my-xxl-1 {
    margin-bottom: 0.25rem !important;
  }
  .ml-xxl-1,
  .mx-xxl-1 {
    margin-left: 0.25rem !important;
  }
  .m-xxl-2 {
    margin: 0.5rem !important;
  }
  .mt-xxl-2,
  .my-xxl-2 {
    margin-top: 0.5rem !important;
  }
  .mr-xxl-2,
  .mx-xxl-2 {
    margin-right: 0.5rem !important;
  }
  .mb-xxl-2,
  .my-xxl-2 {
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem !important;
  }
  .ml-xxl-2,
  .mx-xxl-2 {
    margin-left: 0.5rem !important;
  }
  .m-xxl-3 {
    margin: 1rem !important;
  }
  .mt-xxl-3,
  .my-xxl-3 {
    margin-top: 1rem !important;
  }
  .mr-xxl-3,
  .mx-xxl-3 {
    margin-right: 1rem !important;
  }
  .mb-xxl-3,
  .my-xxl-3 {
    margin-bottom: 1rem !important;
  }
  .ml-xxl-3,
  .mx-xxl-3 {
    margin-left: 1rem !important;
  }
  .m-xxl-4 {
    margin: 1.5rem !important;
  }
  .mt-xxl-4,
  .my-xxl-4 {
    margin-top: 1.5rem !important;
  }
  .mr-xxl-4,
  .mx-xxl-4 {
    margin-right: 1.5rem !important;
  }
  .mb-xxl-4,
  .my-xxl-4 {
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem !important;
  }
  .ml-xxl-4,
  .mx-xxl-4 {
    margin-left: 1.5rem !important;
  }
  .m-xxl-5 {
    margin: 3rem !important;
  }
  .mt-xxl-5,
  .my-xxl-5 {
    margin-top: 3rem !important;
  }
  .mr-xxl-5,
  .mx-xxl-5 {
    margin-right: 3rem !important;
  }
  .mb-xxl-5,
  .my-xxl-5 {
    margin-bottom: 3rem !important;
  }
  .ml-xxl-5,
  .mx-xxl-5 {
    margin-left: 3rem !important;
  }
  .p-xxl-0 {
    padding: 0 !important;
  }
  .pt-xxl-0,
  .py-xxl-0 {
    padding-top: 0 !important;
  }
  .pr-xxl-0,
  .px-xxl-0 {
    padding-right: 0 !important;
  }
  .pb-xxl-0,
  .py-xxl-0 {
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
  }
  .pl-xxl-0,
  .px-xxl-0 {
    padding-left: 0 !important;
  }
  .p-xxl-1 {
    padding: 0.25rem !important;
  }
  .pt-xxl-1,
  .py-xxl-1 {
    padding-top: 0.25rem !important;
  }
  .pr-xxl-1,
  .px-xxl-1 {
    padding-right: 0.25rem !important;
  }
  .pb-xxl-1,
  .py-xxl-1 {
    padding-bottom: 0.25rem !important;
  }
  .pl-xxl-1,
  .px-xxl-1 {
    padding-left: 0.25rem !important;
  }
  .p-xxl-2 {
    padding: 0.5rem !important;
  }
  .pt-xxl-2,
  .py-xxl-2 {
    padding-top: 0.5rem !important;
  }
  .pr-xxl-2,
  .px-xxl-2 {
    padding-right: 0.5rem !important;
  }
  .pb-xxl-2,
  .py-xxl-2 {
    padding-bottom: 0.5rem !important;
  }
  .pl-xxl-2,
  .px-xxl-2 {
    padding-left: 0.5rem !important;
  }
  .p-xxl-3 {
    padding: 1rem !important;
  }
  .pt-xxl-3,
  .py-xxl-3 {
    padding-top: 1rem !important;
  }
  .pr-xxl-3,
  .px-xxl-3 {
    padding-right: 1rem !important;
  }
  .pb-xxl-3,
  .py-xxl-3 {
    padding-bottom: 1rem !important;
  }
  .pl-xxl-3,
  .px-xxl-3 {
    padding-left: 1rem !important;
  }
  .p-xxl-4 {
    padding: 1.5rem !important;
  }
  .pt-xxl-4,
  .py-xxl-4 {
    padding-top: 1.5rem !important;
  }
  .pr-xxl-4,
  .px-xxl-4 {
    padding-right: 1.5rem !important;
  }
  .pb-xxl-4,
  .py-xxl-4 {
    padding-bottom: 1.5rem !important;
  }
  .pl-xxl-4,
  .px-xxl-4 {
    padding-left: 1.5rem !important;
  }
  .p-xxl-5 {
    padding: 3rem !important;
  }
  .pt-xxl-5,
  .py-xxl-5 {
    padding-top: 3rem !important;
  }
  .pr-xxl-5,
  .px-xxl-5 {
    padding-right: 3rem !important;
  }
  .pb-xxl-5,
  .py-xxl-5 {
    padding-bottom: 3rem !important;
  }
  .pl-xxl-5,
  .px-xxl-5 {
    padding-left: 3rem !important;
  }
  .m-xxl-n1 {
    margin: -0.25rem !important;
  }
  .mt-xxl-n1,
  .my-xxl-n1 {
    margin-top: -0.25rem !important;
  }
  .mr-xxl-n1,
  .mx-xxl-n1 {
    margin-right: -0.25rem !important;
  }
  .mb-xxl-n1,
  .my-xxl-n1 {
    margin-bottom: -0.25rem !important;
  }
  .ml-xxl-n1,
  .mx-xxl-n1 {
    margin-left: -0.25rem !important;
  }
  .m-xxl-n2 {
    margin: -0.5rem !important;
  }
  .mt-xxl-n2,
  .my-xxl-n2 {
    margin-top: -0.5rem !important;
  }
  .mr-xxl-n2,
  .mx-xxl-n2 {
    margin-right: -0.5rem !important;
  }
  .mb-xxl-n2,
  .my-xxl-n2 {
    margin-bottom: -0.5rem !important;
  }
  .ml-xxl-n2,
  .mx-xxl-n2 {
    margin-left: -0.5rem !important;
  }
  .m-xxl-n3 {
    margin: -1rem !important;
  }
  .mt-xxl-n3,
  .my-xxl-n3 {
    margin-top: -1rem !important;
  }
  .mr-xxl-n3,
  .mx-xxl-n3 {
    margin-right: -1rem !important;
  }
  .mb-xxl-n3,
  .my-xxl-n3 {
    margin-bottom: -1rem !important;
  }
  .ml-xxl-n3,
  .mx-xxl-n3 {
    margin-left: -1rem !important;
  }
  .m-xxl-n4 {
    margin: -1.5rem !important;
  }
  .mt-xxl-n4,
  .my-xxl-n4 {
    margin-top: -1.5rem !important;
  }
  .mr-xxl-n4,
  .mx-xxl-n4 {
    margin-right: -1.5rem !important;
  }
  .mb-xxl-n4,
  .my-xxl-n4 {
    margin-bottom: -1.5rem !important;
  }
  .ml-xxl-n4,
  .mx-xxl-n4 {
    margin-left: -1.5rem !important;
  }
  .m-xxl-n5 {
    margin: -3rem !important;
  }
  .mt-xxl-n5,
  .my-xxl-n5 {
    margin-top: -3rem !important;
  }
  .mr-xxl-n5,
  .mx-xxl-n5 {
    margin-right: -3rem !important;
  }
  .mb-xxl-n5,
  .my-xxl-n5 {
    margin-bottom: -3rem !important;
  }
  .ml-xxl-n5,
  .mx-xxl-n5 {
    margin-left: -3rem !important;
  }
  .m-xxl-auto {
    margin: auto !important;
  }
  .mt-xxl-auto,
  .my-xxl-auto {
    margin-top: auto !important;
  }
  .mr-xxl-auto,
  .mx-xxl-auto {
    margin-right: auto !important;
  }
  .mb-xxl-auto,
  .my-xxl-auto {
    margin-bottom: auto !important;
  }
  .ml-xxl-auto,
  .mx-xxl-auto {
    margin-left: auto !important;
  }
}
```